# Bounty reward for co-winner

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, expired-bounty

I was participating to a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802825/issue-with-nant-and-nunit2) with another user.

we both have 2 upvote and 0 downvote.

Sadly none of us find a solution.

According to [bounty documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
> minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's
> no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

The other user took is half reward and I didn't.
Do I miss something?

#### Update

Thanks did not find this [page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)...

Now the question is: why the complete bounty info are only on meta and not on the [official bounty help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) ?

Comment: It states on the FAQ page that: *If two or more eligible answers have the same score (if their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.*

Comment: @MartijnPieters cannot find on the faq page

Comment: Regarding your new question: the meta faq post is maintained by ordinary users like you and me. It's not official. The information there is of course monitored and is usually correct, but still does not come from SE employees. It comes to add to the official information and explain it, not replace it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd maybe they should be linked from official documentation

Comment: @giammin too risky in my opinion. There is always a chance spammer will make his way through and corrupt a faq post - or even more likely, user with only 100 rep who rage quit can edit such faq to something horrible and until someone else spot and fix this, it's messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a bounty is not manually awarded, the system will automatically award half the bounty amount to **one** answer.

This is what happened.

The tie breaker between the two answers is the answer date - earlier one gets it.

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> If two or more eligible answers have the same score (if their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.